# Problema com jQuery.ajax php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli

Boas, estou com um problema que não faço a ideia o que seija. Já tentei fazer de todo mas nada. É o seguinte estou a fazer um chat php mas esta a dar um erro do alert():

> ERROR!

```
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.chat_msg', function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var text = jQuery(this).val();
            var idS = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'MPOST',
                url: 'sys/submsg.php',
                data: {mensagem: text, de: idS},
                success: function(retorno){
                    if (retorno == 'ok') {
                        jQuery('.chat_msg').val('');
                    }else{
                        alert('ERROR!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

O OUTRO SCRIPT sys/submsg.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_MPOST["mensagem"])) { 
        @include_once('BD.class.php');

        $mensagem = utf8_decode(strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mensagem', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))));
        $de = (int)$_MPOST['de'];
        $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$de); 
        $content = json_decode($url, true);

        $name = htmlspecialchars($content['response']['players'][0]['personaname']);
        $avatar = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
        $urlName = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];

        if($mensagem != ''){
            $insert = BD::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `chat` (name,avatar,url,mensagem) VALUES (?,?,?,? ");
            $arrayInsert = array($name,$avatar,$urlName,$mensagem);
            if($insert->execute($arrayInsert)){
                echo 'ok';
            }else{
                echo 'off';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

É como se submite.php não tive se a dar pk o retorno não esta a receber nada 
Agradeço a quem me poder ajudar :)

Comment: Falta um `)` aqui: `VALUES (?,?,?,? "`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas alterações:

- Usa o método `POST` pro request pois o jQuery usa `GET` quando não tem esse parâmetro defenido
- Mudei a query, fechando o `VALUES()`, faltava-lhe o último `)`.

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.chat_msg', function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var text = jQuery(this).val();
            var idS = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sys/submsg.php',
                data: {mensagem: text, de: idS},
                success: function(retorno){
                    if (retorno == 'ok') {
                        jQuery('.chat_msg').val('');
                    }else{
                        alert('ERROR!');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["mensagem"])) { 
        @include_once('BD.class.php');

        $mensagem = utf8_decode(strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mensagem', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))));
        $de = (int)$_POST['de'];
        $url = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$de); 
        $content = json_decode($url, true);

        $name = htmlspecialchars($content['response']['players'][0]['personaname']);
        $avatar = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
        $urlName = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];

        if($mensagem != ''){
            $insert = BD::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `chat` (name,avatar,url,mensagem) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ");
            $arrayInsert = array($name,$avatar,$urlName,$mensagem);
            if($insert->execute($arrayInsert)){
                echo 'ok';
            }else{
                echo 'off';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Funcionou Obrigado :)